# What is the order of a coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I'm trying to read [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) on wikipedia (The abelian part of Proof 1) and they say that $G/H$ contains an element of order $p$. What does the order of a right coset mean? Is it the number of elements in the right coset?

Comment: $G/H$ is a group, so the order of its elements are defined in the same way they are for elements of any other group.

Comment: Not "albenian" but "abelian", meaning "commutative". Named for the Norwegian mathematican Niels Henrik Abel.

Comment: @MPW:  Also it is better to write caps $A$ for " **abel**ian ".

Comment: @ChinnapparajR : It is perhaps surprising that this word in particular is usually spelled with lowercase "a" rather than being capitalized; both are in use, though. Other words of this type (Eulerian, Jacobian, etc) are usually capitalized, but abelian is not.

Comment: Yes I agree. Some are used capitalized word while the others are not. For example, Gallian thoroughly used the capitalized word in his book while Herstein and others are  not  used this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, consider $G:=\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. It has an element of order $3$. It means we produce an element $r+\Bbb Z$ such that $3(r+\Bbb Z)=(r+\Bbb Z)+(r+\Bbb Z)+(r+\Bbb Z)=3r+\Bbb Z=0+\Bbb Z$. Such an element here is $\frac{1}{3}+\Bbb Z$

$\frac{1}{3}+\Bbb Z$ is a single element of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ here, eventhough it is a coset, because $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is itself a group.